# Что случилось с БД Mongodb? Как закрыть доступ для внешних IP

Tags: mongodb

Доброго времени суток! Жила-была БД Mongodb подключенных к сайту на VPS.  Версия 2.6. Я ее не трогал. Ничего не добавлял - только обращался через сайт. Семь дней и семь ночей не было никаких нареканий. И вот сегодня,  все коллекции в БД исчезли. Стало пусто. Но появилась новая БД "Warning", тоже пустая. Чтобы это может значить? Куда посмотреть, чтобы узнать, что произошло?

П.С. Нашел пока лишь только одну зацепку. В MongoDB версии ниже 3.0, разрешен доступ с внешних IP. Проверил - смог подключится к БД сайта удаленно. Говорят, для того, чтобы закрыть доступ для внешних IP необходимо внести изменения в файл конфигурации `mongod.conf`, а именно: нужно добавить или внести изменения в строку `bind_ip` и указать `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`. И тогда, якобы для внешних IP доступ будет закрыт. Но вот проблема - в моем конфиге - есть такая строка, с таким значением, а подключение с локального компьютера к БД сайта  происходит. Как же все таки закрыть доступ для внешних IP?

Comment: фаервол (iptables) поможет ограничить доступ. А что бы узнать, что произошло, нужно искать логи, а также делать бекапы. Хотя не исключаю, что данные были удалены из-за программной ошибки.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за подсказку, буду изучать. А на счет ошибки...могло, конечно, что-то быть, но вот есть тема соседняя...могла ли возникнуть ошибка в двух БД одновременно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778399/mongodb-%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83

Comment: @Дмытрык, Вы уверены, что бд `Warning` пустая? Я интересуюсь с той целью, что недавно столкнулся со случаем, где произошло все тоже само. Появилась бд `Warning` и в ней коллекция `Readme`, в которой было сообщение на ангельском что-то типо "ваши данные надежно зашифрованы на наших серверах, хотите данные - платите бетховены". Попробуйте `use Warning` и затем `db.Readme.find({})`. Просто больно уж случаи похожи.

Comment: @RTK я проверял `show collections` - ничего не выводит. Команда `db.Readme.find({})` - аналогично. Дело в том, что  база работает в тестовом режиме. Никакой ценности она не представляет. В БД был только лишь 1 документ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, что случилось - достоверно не известно. Но все поведение БД, как "до" так и "после" события - указывает на то, что это был акт вандализма).
Для закрытия "дыры", воспользовался `iptables`, как и советовали в комментариях. К тому же, я нашел пошаговые инструкции по его настройке на рус. языке:

1)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-tHrAd8IWM - видео

2)http://blondiecode-lh.tumblr.com/post/155619863016/kraken0indiacom-mongodb-drop-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 - текст

3) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/ - документация

Дальше выдержка из текста по ссылке №2 (на всякий случай):

1. Если ваша база не должна быть доступна по сети, просто запретите ей слушать любые `ip`, кроме `localhost`. 
   Для этого зайдите в `mongod.conf` (для стандартной конфигурации ubuntu это `/etc/mongod.conf`) и откомментируйте или допишите правило:
   `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`

Если вам требуется доступ к базе с других ip-адресов, переходите к пункту 2.

2. Запретите всем, кроме ваших серверов, включая локальный, доступ к порту, который слушает `mongodb` (по умолчанию это порт `27017`)! 
   Для `linux-серверов` это можно сделать при помощи `iptables`. 
   Важно! В `iptables` правила выполняются одно за другим, поэтому вы сначала разрешаете к порту доступ с определенного `ip` и только после этого запрещаете доступ для других. Если это не соблюдать, все пакеты будут запрещены и работать не будет.

для того, чтобы сервер мог работать с локальной базой

`iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT`

пропишите правила для внешних адресов ваших серверов, которые обращаются к базе (для каждого сервера свое правило)

`iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A INPUT -s yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT`

запретите доступ всем остальным адресам к этому порту

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j DROP`

Для того, чтобы проверить конфигурацию iptables используйте команду
`iptables -L -n`

при необходимости сбросить полностью все правила, достаточно ввести
`iptables -F`

Важно! Эти правила будут действовать до перезагрузки сервера.
Поэтому, если какое-то правило сработало неверно или вы потеряли доступ к своему серверу, просто перезагрузите свою машину. 
Для того, чтобы правила действовали после перезагрузки используйте `iptables-persistent`
Установка 
`sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent`

Если правила у вас настроены, а `iptables-peristent` не установлен, то при установке, правила будут сохранены автоматически. 
Чтобы запустить сервис

`service iptables-persistent save`
`service iptables-persistent start`

Правила сохраняются в /etc/iptables/rules.v4 и /etc/iptables/rules.v6