# MongoDB. Внезапно пропали все коллекции. Как найти причину?

Tags: linux, mongodb

На данном сервере у меня есть несколько БД в Монго.
Сегодня увидел, что со вчерашнего дня пропали все коллекции во всех базах данных (программно БД между собой никак не связаны). При этом Монго продолжил работать. Некоторые коллекции (те, от которых и следовало того ожидать) создались заново с нуля...
Не знаю, может ли это иметь отношение к проблеме, но отмечу, что сервер (в особенности БД) весьма слабый и очень загруженный.
Как и где начинать искать пропавшие данные?
Буду очень рад любой помощи.

Comment: Эм.. В бэкапе не вариант?

Comment: @Qwertiy К сожалению, никаких бэкапов я настроить еще не успел...

Comment: Посмотрите - кажется у нас схожие проблемы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777830/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%91%D0%94-mongodb-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-ip

Comment: @Дмытрык Наиболее вероятное объяснение происходящего - мировой заговор... Нужно обязательно найти заговорщиков и наказать. У Вас сервер не на DigitalOcean случайно?

Comment: Не, у меня FreeHost